# _.each in underscore chain

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm REALLY confused by chaining in underscore.  Trying to figure out how to use _.each in my chain but not getting any value.

```
_(project.deliverables).each(function(project.deliverables){return deliverable}).findWhere(deliverable.reverse(), {public:true}).value()
```

Is it possible to use _.each in my chain? How do I specify what value is going into the _.each function?

Where's what I'm trying to convert into a chain.

```
_.each(project.deliverables, function(deliverable){

        //get the highest step  in the array that's public
    _.findWhere(deliverable.steps.reverse(), {public:true}, function(step){


            //get the highest version in the versions array that's public
        _.findWhere(step.versions, {public:true}, function(version){

            return version.assets[0].imageurl
          })
   })
})
```

--------**UPDATE**--------

Ok got a working version, but surely there's a simpler way to do it, no?

```
    var x = _.map(project.deliverables, function(v){

            return _.chain(v.steps.reverse())
            .filter(function (x) { return x.public ===true })
            .pluck('versions')
            .first()
            .pluck('assets')
            .first()
            .filter(function(d){return d.url!==undefined})
            .first()
            .pick('url').value()

        })
```

Comment: `project.deliverables` is not a valid parameter name for a function.

Comment: Are you sure you want `each` and not `map`?

Comment: What do you want to use `each` for in here? Or are you looking for `map` actually?

Comment: Could you write your expected functionality without a chain so that we can understand what you want?

Comment: `_.each` simply returns the original list so that the call can be chained. You might be looking for `_.reduce`

Comment: Some input data and desired output would be helpful.